# Login logoff time of Windows system php

Tags: php

1.How to get the user login logoff time of Windows user in PHP

2.Is there any way i can get current user name logged into the system

Thanks in advance

Comment: You means the window's username ?

Comment: For the user or the server?  You can't as PHP is run server-side.  However, you could create an auth system using windows logins

Comment: How can i create an auth system using windows logins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can use javascript to get the current time from user's client and then send it to server by ajax
2. if you already stored the user's information in database, then you can understand which user is logged in just now. just use **SESSION**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with php, But you can use  Windows® Event Viewer to do it

1. Press Windows + R and type “eventvwr.msc” and click OK or press Enter.
2. Expand Windows Logs, and select  Security.
3. In the middle you’ll see a list, with Date and Time,Source, Event ID and Task Category. The Task Category pretty much explains the event, Logon, Special Logon, Logoff and other details.